# Understanding the definition of a natural isomorphism

Tags: category-theory, functors

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_transformation#Definition) I can read this:

> If, for every object $X$ in $C$, the morphism $η_X$ is an isomorphism in $D$, then $η$ is said to be a *natural isomorphism* (or sometimes *natural equivalence* or *isomorphism of functors*).

But I don't understand this. I thought that, if $\eta: F \to G$ is a natural transformation; $F, G: C \to D$; and $X \in C$, this implies that $\eta_X \in C$. So I don't understand, how we can talk about *$\eta_X$ is an isomorphism in $D$*.

EDIT:

So does "$\eta$ is natural isomorphism" only imply that $\exists \varepsilon. \forall \eta_X. \exists \varepsilon_X. \eta_X \circ \varepsilon_X = 1_{G(X)} \wedge \varepsilon_X \circ \eta_X = 1_{F(X)}$, where $\circ$ is vertical composition of natural transformations? So is a natural isomorphism just a natural transformation, that happens to be an isomorphism (in the category of functors)?

Comment: Well no. For every object $X\in C$, $\eta_X$ is a morphism $\eta_X : F(X)\rightarrow G(X)$ in $D$, satisfying the square condition.

Comment: It's a little confusing, wading through those commas. Are you saying $\eta$ maps from $F$ to $G$, while $F$ and $G$ both map from $C$ to $D$?

Comment: Yes @GTonyJacobs

Comment: I don't understand the edited question. $\eta_X$ is not a natural transformation (at least, not necessarily). It is just a morphism in the category $D$.

Comment: Always link to the specific Wikipedia page. Here, we have no idea what $\eta$ is defined to be.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft That is true, but I will say it is. Also $\eta_X$ is the component of the natural transformation (I don't know if you can still call it a nat. trans. itself).

Comment: I am not sure what you mean that you will say it is. It is a natural transformation iff the morphisms in $D$ are natural transformations, which seems like a much more restrictive setup than you are looking for.

Comment: By saying "I say it is", I mean that I declare that both axioms necessary for natural transformations hold true. And I don't know what part of my setup necessitates less restrictions

Comment: So you are for some reason restricting your self to the case where $D$ is the category of functors? I am not saying you need to put less restrictions, I am saying that it is unnecessary to put so many.

Comment: No I don't mean it like that. By _(in the category of functors)_, I don't mean that $D$ is the category of functors (it is an arbitrary category), but rather that $\eta_{X}$ being a natural transformation is equivalent to saying, that $\eta$ is an isomorphism of $F$ in the category of functors (with the objects being $F, G$, the morphisms being $\eta, \varepsilon$, etc.)

Comment: But $\eta_X$ is not a natural transformation. $\eta$ is, and this means that $\eta_X$ is a morphism in $D$ from $F(X)$ to $G(X)$ (plus some more stuff about these morphisms being compatible).

Comment: Actually, I think I am starting to see what the issue is. Usually being an isomorphism means having an inverse. But here it is defined as each component having an inverse. I leave it as a nice exercise to show that indeed $\eta$ itself also has an inverse in the category of functors and natural transformations.

Comment: Ok, so let me rephrase it: Is *$\eta$* being a *natural isomorphism* equivalent to saying, that \eta is an isomorphism of $F$ in the category of functors (with the objects being $F, G$, the morphisms being $\eta, \varepsilon$, etc.)?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, and as I said, it is a nice exercise to prove this (you need to define an inverse and show that it satisfies the conditions of being a natural transformation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A natural transformation $\eta$ maps objects of a category $\mathcal C$ to *arrows* of a category $\mathcal D$. 
Specifically, if $F,G:\mathcal C\to\mathcal D,\ \ x\in Ob\mathcal C\ $ and $\eta:F\to G$, we have $\eta_x$ is an arrow $F(x)\to G(x)$ in $\mathcal D$.

A natural transformation $\eta$ is a natural isomorphism if

- each component $\eta_x$ is an isomorphism (invertible arrow in $\mathcal D$)
- equivalently, if $\eta$ itself is an isomorphism (invertible arrow) in the category $Fun(\mathcal C,\mathcal D)$ of functors $\mathcal C\to\mathcal D$ with natural transformations as arrows.

> To see the equivalence, observe that composition of natural transformations in $Fun(\mathcal C,\mathcal D)$ is done 'componentwise', i.e. $(\eta\circ\psi)_x=\eta_x\circ\psi_x$, so that the inverse can also be taken componentwise.